# The array runs, but does not give the correct values when compiled?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, count, random-seed

I simply don't know where I'm getting it wrong. I've included the whole code. I'm trying to get the percentage part to display 30 distinct values, but it keeps displaying 29. Is there a simple fix to this and am I making this too complicated?

```
private static final Scanner
   stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

   private static Random 
   rng;


   public static void main (String[] args){

    long
       rngSeed;

    int
       numberOfFlips,
       totalNumberOfRuns = 1,
       run = 0;


     boolean
       theCoin,
       tempVal = false;

   System.out.println("Welcome to the coin flip analyzer.\n" +
    "How many flips?");
   numberOfFlips = stdIn.nextInt();
   System.out.println("What do you want to seed the random number generator with?");
   rngSeed = stdIn.nextLong();

   int[]runLength = new int[50];
   rng = new Random(rngSeed);

   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++) {
       theCoin = rng.nextBoolean();
       if (i > 0 && theCoin != tempVal) {
          if (i < 50) {
              System.out.print(run + " ");
         }
          runLength[run - 1]++;
          totalNumberOfRuns++;
          run = 1;
      }
       else
           run++;
       if (theCoin) {
           if (i < 50) {
               System.out.print("H");
           }
           tempVal = true;
       }
       else {
           if (i < 50) {
               System.out.print("T");
           }
           tempVal = false;
       }
   }


   System.out.print("...");
   System.out.println();

   System.out.println("There were a total of " + totalNumberOfRuns +
    " distinct runs in the simulation.\nTheir breakdown follows.");


   // run length table header line

    System.out.println("[run length] = # (as percentage of all runs)");

   // your code to display the count and frequency percentage of each run length
   // should follow

    for (int i = 0; i < runLength.length; i++) {
        double percentageFreq = ((double) + (runLength[i]) / (totalNumberOfRuns) * 100);
        if (runLength[i] > 0)
            System.out.println("[" + (i+1) + "] = " + runLength[i] + " (" + String.format("%1.1f", percentageFreq) + " %)");
            }   
      }
}
```

...............

Most Important Part of Outcome Using: 50 flips and a random seed value of 1200.

> H1 T1 H1 T1 HHH3 TTTTT5 H1 T1 HHHH4 T1 HH2 T1 H1 T1 H1 T1 H1 T1 H1 TTT3 H1 TTT3 H1 TTTT4 H1 T1 HHH3 TT2 H1 T...

There were a total of 30 distinct runs in the simulation.

Their breakdown follows.

- [run length] = # (as percentage of all runs)
- [1] = 20 (66.7 %) (I need this to be 21 since the last value is "T").
- [2] = 2 (6.7 %)
- [3] = 4 (13.3 %)
- [4] = 2 (6.7 %)
- [5] = 1 (3.3 %)

...............

Comment: You should edit your question according to the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. The ultimate reason why it's not working is that the final coin flip is not being counted.

The reason why your code is outputing `There were a total of 30 distinct runs in the simulation.` is because you start `totalNumberOfRuns` at the wrong value.

`totalNumberOfRuns` should start at `0` rather than `1`.

Also notice how the end of the output for coin flips is `T...`, there should be a `1` following the `T`. You need to place that print statement at the end of the loop, otherwise it will only print the number from the previous iteration and simply not run at all for the final iteration.

Also, throughout your code you use magic numbers. E.g. `if (i < 50)`, `int[]runLength = new int[50]`. Magic numbers are evil and you should never use them. An example of why magic numbers are evil: what if the user enters `100` when asked how many times the coin should be flipped? The code will not run properly in this case. Regardless even if you were not using a magic number here, these conditional statements are pointless because `i` will never be greater than `50` if you enter `50` for `numberOfFlips`.

I also am a bit bothered by the styling in your code. Please please please use curly braces even for blocks that are one line long. At the very least, at least be consistent with it. At some points you use curly braces for single-line if statements, but in one spot you don't use curly braces for a single-line else statement.

Also, your print statement where you output the frequencies is very messy. This is a perfect place to use `System.out.printf`, especially since you are already using `String.format` inside of the print method. The `printf` method is a beautiful thing and you should get comfortable with it. Here is what you should use:

`System.out.printf("[%d] = %d (%1.1f%%)%n", i + 1, runLength[i], percentageFreq);`

I got your code working, and I also cleaned it up a bit. Before you copy and paste this solution, I implore you to think about why my explanation above will fix your code, as well as what I did to clean up your code (e.g. `rng` should not be static)

Here you go :)

```
public class Main {
private static final Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int totalNumberOfRuns = 0;
    int run = 1;
    boolean theCoin, tempVal = false;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the coin flip analyzer.\n"
            + "How many flips?");
    int numberOfFlips = stdIn.nextInt();
    System.out
            .println("What do you want to seed the random number generator with?");
    long rngSeed = stdIn.nextLong();
    Random rng = new Random(rngSeed);
    int[] runLength = new int[numberOfFlips];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++) {
        theCoin = rng.nextBoolean();
        if (theCoin != tempVal) {
            runLength[run - 1]++;
            totalNumberOfRuns++;
            run = 1;
        } else {
            run++;
        }
        if (theCoin) {
            System.out.print("H");
            tempVal = true;
        } else {
            System.out.print("T");
            tempVal = false;
        }
        System.out.print(run + " ");
    }

    System.out.print("...");
    System.out.println();

    System.out
            .println("There were a total of "
                    + totalNumberOfRuns
                    + " distinct runs in the simulation.\nTheir breakdown follows.");

    // run length table header line

    System.out.println("[run length] = # (as percentage of all runs)");

    // your code to display the count and frequency percentage of each run
    // length
    // should follow

    for (int i = 0; i < runLength.length; i++) {
        double percentageFreq = ((double) +(runLength[i])
                / (totalNumberOfRuns) * 100);
        if (runLength[i] > 0) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] = %d (%1.1f%%)%n", i + 1, runLength[i],
                    percentageFreq);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Flaom, I really appreciate it and that makes more sense. I knew it probably had something to do with what I was initializing my variables to. My only question remaining is how can I get rid of that first one, so that it simply starts at H1 or is that not possible? Again, I really appreciate it.

I knew I had some imaginary numbers that needed to go. I've heard of being able to use printf but never thought I could use it in this case.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? When I run it, it does start at H1. Are you getting something else?

Comment: Yes, mine starts with 1, because I need the specific values I mentioned in my reply. Yours does indeed start with H1, but mine starts with 1 because I had to rearrange one part so it would consolidate to what I had in my above comment.

Comment: I believe I got it working the way I need it based off your code and some minor edits to mine! Just needed to edit the percentage portion! Thank you so much for your knowledge!

Comment: Alright, I got everything working. I have another question if you don't mind. I want my output value value to always end at the "H1 T..." portion regardless of what seed value I put in. It will still get different distinct values and such in the process, but it won't display the random distinct values after the "H1 T..." to keep things tidy. Is there a way of doing that? I've tried rearranging my for loop, but it doesn't seem to work entirely.